# Perl colon split show one character

Tags: perl

Perl colon split show one character when using it in variables.

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $serialnumber= "0123456789";
my $macaddr = "a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6";
my $macaddress  = split /:/, $macaddr;

print $macaddress;
print "\n";
```

The result is only "6" or last character of the text.

See image...

[image]

Comment: Still logged in as `root`, eh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sean explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534389/996114) why you are getting `6`. However, instead of using split, just [substitute](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) to get rid of colons:

```
my $macaddr = "a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6";
$macaddr =~ s/://g;

print $macaddr;
# a1b2c3d4e5f6
```

Comment: or `$macaddr =~ y/://d;`

Answer (score 3):

The first paragraph of `perldoc -f split` says:

```
Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the
list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.
```

Be assigning the result of `split` to the scalar variable `$macaddress`, you're providing scalar context, and so you're getting the size of the list back.  It's just a coincidence that this happens to be the same as the last character of your input string.

Comment: There's other solution to fix this?

Comment: @JeromeLaliag What is your desired output?

Comment: a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6 and change it to a1b2c3d4e5f6 then use it in variable, then print the variable.

Comment: @JeromeLaliag See my answer for an easier alternative to split.

Answer (score 0):

You could use split in list context:

```
my @macaddress  = split /:/, $macaddr;
print join "", @macaddress;
```

Comment: The output will be space separated `a1 b2 c3 d4 e5 f6`.